# Cannot Connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (Server Name Issue)

Tags: sql

I have tried any kind of name for `Server Name`, including ".\SQLEXPRESS", "localhost\SQLEXPRESS", "My PC Name", "MyPCName\SQLEXPRESS" but I still get the same error:

Cannot connect to .\SQLEXPRESS.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Comment: Did you click the link and follow the instructions?

Comment: Configured your server, protocols, and firewall for remote connections?

Comment: I've done almost everything mentioned on Microsoft help files and many other websites but I still get the same error!! + The Server list in SQL Server Configuration Manager is completely empty!!!!